# Desktop IE 11(edge) applies mobile CSS, then normal CSS upon window resizing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, internet-explorer, media-queries

If I load my application using IE11(Edge), it loads mobile CSS for the breadcrumbs section, on resizing the browser window causes the actual css to be applied instead.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: IE11 is an entirely different beast from Edge, so which one are you asking about? Also, please update your answer to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your description about the issue is not clear. We have a confusion that which browser you are using IE or Edge? Also you did not post any sample code or snapshot of the issue. If possible than try to provide a detailed information about your issue may help us to understand the issue in better way.